# Why does UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText() return inconsistent results?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I'm looping through a list of Amazon Products to get the negative reviews from each product in the list.
However, about 90% of the time, `UrlFetchApp.fetch("url").getContentText();` will return a short version of the HTML that doesn't contain any of the actual content on the page.

Right now I'm forcing the loop to try again and again until the correct (longer) HTML is returned, but that takes so long. I'm wondering if anyone knows any alternatives or any tricks to make it more consistent?

Here's one of the URLs for example: (Does the dynamic nature of the web-page have anything to do with the inconsistency?)

[https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B00J2DGTD8/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_srt?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=one_star&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1&sortBy=recent#reviews-filter-bar](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00J2DGTD8)

Here's a Minimum Reproducible Example:

```
function mre() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  var star = ["one", "two", "three"];

  for(var a = 0; a < 3; a++) { //star 

    htmlRaw = UrlFetchApp
      .fetch(`https://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B00J2DGTD8/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_viewopt_srt?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=${star[a]}_star&reviewerType=all_reviews&pageNumber=1&sortBy=recent#reviews-filter-bar`).getContentText(); 

    html = htmlRaw.toString();  
  
    //Logger.log(htmlRaw);
    //Logger.log(html);

    //Making sure we have the correct HTML
    //The below if statement acts like a gate. It tries again and again until it receives the correct version of the HTML. Then it will "open the gate" to the else{} below
  
    if(html.substring(100000, 100500) == ``) { //the longer (correct) version of the HTML has 100,000+ characters
      
      Logger.log(`if its empty, then try again: ${html.substring(100000, 100500)}`);
      a--;
    }

    else {

      lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); //so we actually move the down the rows
      sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1).setValue(html.substring(100000, 100500)); //html snippet

    } //else (correct html)
  } //for (a - stars)
} //function mre()
```

Comment: Probably you are getting recognized as a robot and denied service. Use official, authorized means of programmatic access to websites you don't own. Curious why you don't say what the content of the page is when it doesn't load fully...

Comment: Can you provide more details about the response you are getting it doesn't return the expected content? Probably this website blocks automated requests.

Comment: @tehhowch the MRE i provided should show the html when the page doesn't load. And why would amazon not want someone programmatically accessing a public product page? In any case I should probably abandon this script and find a new way to do it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Plenty of companies don't want people scraping data, especially when it is pulled from database queries. Sure, it's cached at the edge, but that's still garbage requests and incorrect traffic for your ads. If people want programmatic access to your data, they can pay for access to your API..